# How to avoid registry cleaners to not remove registry entries created by code

Tags: windows, registry

What I've read in posts about how registry cleaners work, is that the registry cleaners  remove keys that are not being used.

Is there a way to set a reference somewhere for a key in order it to not seem oprhaned? How to ensure the registry cleaners to do not think the registry entries created by code to be not detected as orphaned?

In case that using Installers is the only way to do that. How we can create entries per user for example by using HKEY_CURRENT_USER, since installers run under the user profile of the user that runs the installer and does not have access to other users HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry areas?

Comment: The first thing to note is that nobody should ever use registry cleaners.  They're a Bad Idea.  In terms of trying to protect your application from the ill effects of a registry cleaner ... well, registry cleaners use heuristics to guess whether a key is "being used" or not.  There's no actual reference count or anything similar.  I'm afraid the only answer would be to try to reverse engineer the registry cleaner(s) you are concerned about in order to figure out how to convince them not to kill your application (and hope that it works for the next version too).

Comment: (If you have any kind of technical support contract or agreement with your customers you might want to make "no registry cleaners" one of the conditions.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston, I think this what you suggests is not an option if your application is going to be publicly available.

Comment: I don't see why not.  Just because an application is publicly available does not mean you are obliged to provide any sort of formal technical support, and if you do choose to do so you can put whatever reasonable conditions on it you like.

Comment: Have you actually had specific problems with one or more registry cleaners and your application?  Or are you just concerned that they might cause problems?  Have you considered shipping a repair tool to recreate the registry setting(s) that are going missing?

Comment: @HarryJohnston. I think the second. However I've seen before problems with Registry cleaners removing keys that they should not remove, so the design had to change to store information in files instead of the registry.

Comment: Ouch.  Annoying to have to take a backwards step because some of your customers have been misled by people selling harmful snake oil, but I guess there's no help for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check what is cleaned before applying your choices, ccleaner (among many others) let you choose the entry to delete or not but generally those deleted are useless.